# How can I effectively secure guitar strings to the tuning pegs?

Tags: guitar, tuning, strings

One of the bigger problems I face when restringing my guitars is properly securing the strings to the pegs.

How should I wind the strings around the pegs before tightening them to prevent the string slipping when the tension increases?

My electric guitar is an Aria MAC 57/7 (7 String). I use Ernie Ball Regular Slinky strings. The tuners are whatever is standard on this kind of guitar. I have never changed them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Before putting a string trough a hole, bend it, so it would have an angle a bit more then 90 degrees. Then, when string is inside, start making circles around.

In this video Andrew shows how to do it and why you do it on an acoustic guitar:

Comment: Does this technique differ for electric guitars and/or different types of strings?

Comment: @Jasarien Unfortunately, I do not own an electric guitar, so I cannot tell you this. But as far as I saw, pegs are not too different (if we are comparing with steel string acoustics)

Comment: @Jasarien I use this technique for all of my stringed instruments (not just guitars) - acoustic and electric alike.  In my experience it works well.  Though none of my instruments use nylon strings, so I can't comment on those.

Comment: I find it's best to tie a knot for nylon strings, as the bend is not enough to keep the string from slipping.

Comment: I do this, but a little differently. I turn the hole parallel to the strings, and feed it backward, toward the bridge. Then pull taught. It creates the same bend. But I also maintain that same pull until it's roughly tuned-up and under tension.

Answer (score 6):

What my father showed me how to do is a bit different, and I wish I could post a video or draw a picture. Maybe I will take one and post it. Let me try and explain the method though, take your string, unbent, and slide it through the tuning peg, then loop it around itself, so that when you tighten the tuning peg the string will be holding itself back. you usually need to make a small kink in it like above by pulling tight fir a quick second.

The nice thing about this method is you dont have to sit around and wind anything, the string does all the work.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you leave at least enough slack for the string to go around the post twice.

As you tighten, the protruding end of the string makes a circuit around the post. The first time it passes the business end of the string, guide it *under* the string. The second time it passes, guide it *over* the string.

Now the string wound around the post is pinching the protruding end, stopping it from slipping out. That, combined with the right-angle kink in the string on the opposite side of the post, will hold it tight.

Tune the instrument, and once you're happy, trim off all but 1cm or so of the protruding strings.

This works equally well for nylon and metal strings.

Answer (score 1):

I always try to have about 4 inches worth of string wrapped around the peg. There are further things to do, such as locking tuners and tying the strings, but I find that having sufficient windings (but not too many) should be enough.

Answer (score -1):

The way I have always done it, and works very well. Wrap the string three times around the tuning peg, then stick it through the hole, out the other side in between the wrapped part. Never goes outta tune